# Fractional ideals are isomorphic to relatively prime integral ideals in Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind Domain with fraction field $K$ with nonzero fractional ideals $A$ and $B$ (i.e., $A=d^{-1}I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$ and $d\in R$).

$\mathbf{Problem}$.  Show that there are elements $\alpha,\beta\in K$ such that $\alpha A$ and $\beta B$ are nonzero integral ideals of R that are relatively prime.

I am only trying to understand the problem. If $A=d^{-1}I$ then it seems to me that the only way $\alpha A$ can be an ideal of $R$ is when $d$ divides $\alpha$.  But this seems to be a problem for getting $\alpha A+\beta B=R$.

In a Dedekind Domain every ideal is generated by two elements.  The only thing I can think of is if $I=(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ have no common factors, then maybe this implies that $Ra+Rb=R$, and so we can take $\alpha =\beta =d$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238466/relatively-prime-ideals-in-dedekind-domains

Comment: As far as I can see $\alpha\in K$, so $d\mid\alpha$ in $K$. Anyway, a solution to your problems follows easily from the linked thread.